# How to add separator in EditText Text while typing in Xamarin.Android (C#)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, number-formatting

I have tried in AfterTextChanged event with below code.

Code:

double value = 0;

```
            if (double.TryParse(Text, NumberStyles.Any, this.InternalCulture, out value))
            {
                string formattedString = NumberFormat.GetNumberInstance(CultureInfo).Format(value);

                if (!formattedString.Equals(Text))
                {

                    Text = formattedString;                        
                }

                SetSelection(Text.Length);
            }
```

But while typing dot(.) symbol, TryParse section neglects the dot(.) then passed the value to next line.

Here, Text is EditText.Text property.

SetSelection is EditText.SetSelection() method used to place the cursor after TextChanged.

So I am unable to add separator with decimal (.) point.

Please suggest your valuable answers.

Comment: Some parameters like "Text", "SetSelection", do not have the definition in your description. Could you provide more details for this? And what does the passed the value to next line mean?

Comment: Text property and SetSelection method are related with native EditText.

Comment: I need `this.InternalCulture` and `CultureInfo` for your code. Could you provide mode information with screenshot for me to reproduce this issue ?